# Vs Code shows weird errors on java maven project

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

sometimes vs code gives weird java errors in problems pane. Actually curly braces are true , but it shows errors in the below image.

[image: errors that vscode shows]

I installed these components related to java:

[image: installed components related to java]

How can i solve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: what code giving you errors?

Comment: a lot of code lines , but i can compile the project from intellij idea, so these curly braces are true actually. sometimes vs code shows,sometimes it doesnt show these errors.

Comment: Can't say much with the info provided. Sorry.

Comment: thanks. i think it is related to configuration or maven projects or compilation problems. I use oracle jdk ( not open jdk)